# BlueSnap integration with SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, payment-gateway, bluesnap

I'm managing my customer data in SalesForce and I want to integrate it with BlueSnap so I can create orders with SalesForce;

Are there any limitations I should be aware of?
Where can I find clear instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi – you need to keep in mind the following requirements before you start integrating SalesForce with BlueSnap;
Your SalesForce account must be an “Enterprise or Performance” or “Unlimited” Edition.
Your production BlueSnap account should be active with a PCI level of SAQ C-VT.
You need to setup your soft-descriptor, API username and Payout method in your BlueSnap account.
Your BlueSnap approved IPs should include this address: 204.14.232.100
You can see the requirements and setup instructions in [this page](https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/salesforce?utm_campaign=Merchant%20Newsletter&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=2&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-853zAi7F5EyrpZv2cvbY4FgBVa3CwtPV6owDQfMTvhIdjGFTQGCt8MjDJ7iHe9YoUOw9VXUfMDx7qxvRS1bJ-gk1e7tGWoh-NI4XYXUBCUTu9UTJA&_hsmi=2#section-requirements), and in [here](https://www.appfrontier.com/bluesnap-salesforce-integration.html).

I hope this information is what you were looking for :)

Dan